# Trying to get simple wordpress custom page PHP insert to work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, insert

I have made a custom wordpress page and I'm trying to make an simle form and insert the data to the database.

I have 2 problems.
1. Is my code inserted in the right place in the custom page?
2. This example (found on this forum) gives me a http 500 error. I have tried to solve it for many days now. Please can someone help :)

```
<?php /* Template Name: Storfanger_indberet */ ?>
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" <?php generate_content_class();?>>
<main id="main" <?php generate_main_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action('generate_before_main_content'); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
<!--My code begin -->
<?php
If($_POST['Submit']) {
// run validation if you're not doing it in js
global $wpdb;
$coursename=$_POST['coursename'];
$coursename1=$_POST['coursevalue'];
$coursecategory=$_POST['coursecategory'];
if($wpdb->insert(
'ct_storfanger_indberetninger',
array(
'name' => $coursename,
'email' => $coursename1,
'message' =>$coursecategory
)
) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database
insertion successful<p />';
?>
<a href="" onClick="return false;" id="addcatch">Indberet endnu en fangst.</a>
<?php
                    }
else // else we didn't submit the form, so display the form
{
?>

<form action="" method="post" id="addcatch">
<label id="coursename">Course Name:<input type="text" name="coursename" size="30" /></label>
<label id="coursevalue">Points Value:<input type="text" name="coursevalue" size="10"  /></label>
<label id="coursecategory">Course Category:<select name="coursecategory" size="1">
<option selected>Product Knowledge</option>
<option>Demonstrate Effectively</option>
<option>Perfect Your Pitch</option>
<option>Business Integration and Technical Training</option>
</select></label>

                <p> </p>
                <p> </p>
                </div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="addcoursesubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<a href="" onClick="return false;" id="addcatch">Add Another Course.</a>
                <?php
                } // end else no post['submit']
                {
                ?>

                <!--My code ends -->

                <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' !=get_comments_number() ) : ?>
                    <div class="comments-area">
                        <?php comments_template(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
            <?php do_action('generate_after_main_content'); ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php 
    do_action('generate_sidebars');
     get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: In particular I notice a syntax error around `// end else no post['submit']`.

Comment: I found the problem in my own code.